# Switching to Webview context fails

Tags: selenium, android, appium

I was trying to automate tests for a hybrid app, while switching, it only shows name native context. WebView Context is shown as webview_undefined.

```
Set<String>  contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) 
{
     System.out.println(contextName);
     if (contextName .contains("WEBVIEW"))
     {
         driver.context(contextName); 
        webViewFound = true; 
        System.out.println("switched to webview");
    }
}
```

I'm using the above code. Can anyone give solution for this !

Answer (score 1):

Dinesh, Give a try to below snippet

```
Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

String parent = it.next();
String child = it.next();

driver.switchTo().window(child);
//perform actions on child window

driver.close(); // only for child wondow


driver.switchTo().window(parent);
//perform actions on parent window

driver.quit(); // After execution of main thread and for parent window
```